Does an interchangeability exist between Complex Gaussian distribution and Rayleigh distribution?
Suppose, a complex Gaussian distribution is given by:
$$N\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$$
It can also be written as:
$$N=X+jY$$ where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1/2)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1/2)$, both $X$ and $Y$ are distributed Normally and are independent of one another.
Now, we know that for independent Gaussian distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$, $|r|=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is distributed as Rayleigh distribution and $\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$ is distributed uniformly.
Questions:

Are Complex Gaussian and Rayleigh & uniform distributions respective Cartesian and Polar forms of the same quantity, i.e., $N=X+jY=|r|\exp{(j\theta)}$?

Can we replace  complex Gaussian distribution with joint distribution of $f_{R,\theta}(r,\theta)$?


PS: this question was earlier asked on Cross Validated but I do not receive an answer or comment. Therefore I have deleted the question there  and I am posting it here.

Euclidean $\mathbb R^2$  and $\mathbb C$ are nearly identical. The euclidean scalar product is supplied by $$(u+iv)(x-iy)=(u x + v y) + i (v x-uy) $$ generating the cross product as its imaginary part automatically, thats a pseudoscalar in $\mathbb R^2$.
The group of locally orthonormal coordinate transforms in $\mathbb R ^2$ are   automatically implemented as the group of conformal transformation by any analytic function in $\mathbb C$ over a simply connected domain of interest.
So for two independent gaussian random variables $X,Y$ any analytic function $f$ by  $$\Re f(X+i Y), \Im f(X+iY)$$  provides a pair of independent random variables by the fact that the distribution is the integral over $$ dx \wedge dy =\frac{1}{2i} \ d(x-i\ dy)\wedge d(x+i \ y) = \frac{1}{2i} \ df(\overline w) \wedge df(w )$$ that splits into a product of independent integrals, if the product of the Jacobian and the common density factorizes in the new variables.

Thanks for answer. I am no mathematician, just know a little math. I always used to think that $mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as complex plane. May be I need to read a lot because you said they are nearly identical, Are there some references where I can get an in depth discussion of complex random variables and their difference with two-variable random vector

It is a good place to recall how to answer  the question: 'How to create  two independent rv $X,Y$ which are $N(0,1)$ using two independent uniform rv $U,V$ on $(0,1)$. Answer: define $R=\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{U}}$ and $$X=\sqrt{2}R\cos(2\pi V),\ Y=\sqrt{2}R\sin(2\pi V).$$
